# Increasing of max (more than 10) TCP Connections

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, tcp, connection

I have the following problem on one of my servers:

[image: Graph of TCP Connections monitor]

On other servers max TCP Connections is dynamical and much more higher than 10.

How to increase max TCP Connections in this server in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a misconception on your side - the graph display of the resource monitor does not always auto-scale correctly, so what your graph is showing is that you have at least 10 currently open TCP connections, not that you have a maximum of 10 TCP connections. If you need to know the exact current number of open TCP connections, you could just use `netstat -n | find /C /I "established"` on the command line use Perfmon to monitor the "Established connections" counter value of the TCPv4 group.

Comment: Ok, but then how to remove the graph limit of 10 TCP connections ? - I cannot manage to force it to auto-scale properly.

Comment: @Chucky This is just a bug in the resource monitor. If you need a graph over time for the number of connections, you might use `perfmon` instead to display *TCPv4 / Connections Established* and *TCPv6 / Connections Established*

Comment: This should be the same number listed as "current connections" when you run "netstat -s"

Answer (score 1):

The limit of 10 half-open TCP connections introduced in XP has been removed as of Vista/Server 2008 SP2 (which can be re-enabled by a [registry tweak](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969710)). Server 2008 R2 does not have this limitation.